# error handling for duplicate key in mongoDB

Tags: mongodb, error-handling, indexing

i have a collection in mongoDB . and i create a unique index on "word" filed of it.

i have a method like below for add to collection:

```
private boolean add(String word, Map<String, Integer> docOccurrence, Map<String, Integer> totalOccurrence) {
    db.requestStart();
    BasicDBObject document = new BasicDBObject();
    document.put(DB_COLLECTION_WORD_CAT_COL_WORD, SQLQueryValidation.validateBeforeWrite(word));
    document.put(DB_COLLECTION_WORD_CAT_COL_DOC_OCCURRENCE, new BasicDBObject(docOccurrence));
    document.put(DB_COLLECTION_WORD_CAT_COL_TOTAL_OCCURRENCE, new BasicDBObject(totalOccurrence));
    try {
        synchronized (LOCK_WRITE) {
            table.save(document, WriteConcern.SAFE);
            //System.out.println(wr.getField("ok"));
        }
    } catch (MongoException e) {
        System.out.println("heh");
        logger.error("Could not insert new row to word_cat : {}", e.getMessage());
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

but if i insert a repitative word, i get this error!

```
 Could not insert new row to word_cat : insertDocument :: caused by :: 11000 E11000       duplicate key error index: cat.word_cat_english.$word_1  dup key: {"test_word" }
```

i expect it dosn't have problem because using .save instead of .insert

i already used Cassandra and it has automatic upsert.

how can i manage it?

and totaly what is the best way for error handling in mongoDB?

thanks.

Comment: MongoDB "save" operated on the _id value of the document. So in your case it would only update the original document if you set the _id value to the same one inserted originally. One potential way to handle this would be to set _id yourself to the WORD value, given this makes sense for your data model and use cases.

Answer (score 0):

I second 'zsh''s answer above. In other words, how could mongo guess whether you're mistakenly trying to insert duplicates, or trying to update an existing data.
I would either:

1) Run a 'select by word', and if such a document already exists - save with its ID

2) Use mongo upsert :
http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.update/

Just a word of warning, when I used spring-data-mongo the 2nd approach was more 'low level' and less 'object oriented', e.g. spring implementation wouldn't dispatch events and wouldn't perform optimistic updates (though you might want to double-check that, I used an old version).